# Fetching recently added friends using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Its more over a question if it can be done, than how to do it.  Using FQL, I fetched the friend's UIDs and I see it is arranged in ascending order i.e the person who joined first in fb becomes the first UID when I fetch the uids.

Is there any way to see the last person I added? If it isnt possible directly, maybe we could fetch the date that 2 people became friends and then compare to see the latest one?

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Based on the related FQL tables, I don't see a field that would help you achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I thought. So there is no way to find the our last friend?

Comment: @Kishor This query will give you the ids arranged in descending order. `SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ORDER BY uid2 DESC`. I don't think there is a way of finding out when you became friends with someone.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by looking for friend announcements with the `stream` table:

```
 SELECT description, description_tags, type, created_time FROM stream 
    WHERE source_id = me() AND type = 8 LIMIT 50
```

The `type=8` limits this to stream posts that are friend announcements.

Of course, you are limited to the normal restrictions of the `stream` table: the greater of 50 posts or 30 days worth of posts, so even finding the last friend announcement could require multiple FQL calls.

Comment: That sums up there is no chance to find the first friend right. Duh.

Comment: I wouldn't say "no chance". With enough time and queries, you could eventually suss that out. However, Facebook has made this very difficult by design, and an app like this probably violates the TOS anyway.

Comment: How would it violate the TOS o.O

Comment: See 1.3: "You must not circumvent our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality." I would interpret not being able to find the date two users became friends as an intended limitation.